# <p/> tag in Javadoc in IntelliJ / Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, phpstorm, javadoc

There is the small  tag which is created at some places if I reformat the code in Android Studio and other Jetbrains products as well.

How can I prevent that?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `<p/>` tag is generated on empty lines so that they are shown in the javadocs.

If you want to, you can turn this off when you reformat the code.

In Android Studio, go to File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> JavaDoc tab -> Uncheck `Generate "<p/>" on empty lines`

[image: Where to turn off generation of the p tag]

Here is what the documentation will look like with and without the paragraph tag, where on the right is the text from the quick docs window.

[image: Example of the docs with and without p tag.]

Just take that into consideration.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it´s created on empty lines, but not on all. In about 90% of my javadocs I don´t have this tag

Comment: @Nachbar90 You only get the tag if you reformat the code. Does my answer fix your issue?

Comment: yes i know but it doesn´t fill in the tag everywhere! yes it did, thank you

Comment: @Nachbar90 ohhh I see. That's odd. Not sure why, haven't had that happen to me so far. No problem!

Comment: FYI: It's a bit messy but for Java 8 project language level "Generate <p/> on empty lines" means "Generate <p> on empty lines" ;)

Comment: The problem I have is that when I format it also changes <p> to <p/>. The first one creates a new line, the second one creates a new line with extra space (like a new paragraph).